# Django View & Form Inheritance

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to change the password change form for my custom user auth django project.  I am running into a bit of a problem.  Perhaps I am too tired, perhaps I am wrong or misunderstanding things, which is why I am seeking help.  I know it seems like a lot of work for such a small thing but I am trying to create a 'canned' auth app.  My goal with this particular problem is simply to apply style to the PasswordChangeForm(SetPasswordForm) class without the aid\dependency of non-native packages.  Am I wrong in my thought process here?  urls calls a view that inherits from the auth view which points to a form that inherits from auth form with changed field values.  Thanks in advance.

**urls.py**

```
from .views import ChangePasswordView
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    PasswordChangeDoneView,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('change_password/',
        ChangePasswordView,
        name='password_change'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView
    from .forms import ChangePasswordForm

    @login_required
    class ChangePasswordView(PasswordChangeView):
        template_name='account/change_password_form.html'
        form_class = ChangePasswordForm
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
    PasswordChangeForm,
    SetPasswordForm,
)

class ChangePasswordForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    template_name='account/change_password_form.html'
    old_password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Old password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autofocus': True, 'placeholder': 'Password',
                               'class': 'form-control', 'required': 'true'}),
    )

    new_password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("New Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password',
                               'class': 'form-control', 'required': 'true'}),
    )

    new_password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Confirm Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password',
                               'class': 'form-control', 'required': 'true'}),
```

the error

> TypeError at /account/change_password/
>   **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0):

It's always the little things...

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('change_password/',
        ChangePasswordView,
        name='password_change'),
]
```

should be

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('change_password/',
        ChangePasswordView.as_view(),
        name='password_change'),
]
```

It's late! You're tired! Get it working, then get some sleep. :-)

Comment: I wish that were the case.  It's something I already had in my code, which I took out.  `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'`

Comment: Oh wait - it should be `url(...)` not `path(...)`, no?

Comment: In 2.0 it's path

Comment: They're eliminating the incessant need to type `url(r'^......../$',...)` in every friggen URL - YAY!

Comment: Ah, 2.0 - that explains my confusion. Docs seem to imply that as_view() should still be needed for class based views though...

Comment: You can see from the source files that `as_view` is still a thing.  But, for some reason I get the aforementioned error.  I looked through some of the source to see what exactly `as_view` does to see how I can implement it, but didn't find much to go on.

Comment: I wonder if the `@classonlymethod` decorator prevents the as_view function from being inherited..   hmm..  https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.contrib.auth.views/PasswordChangeView/

Comment: I think I figured out your `'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'` error issue - you're using the login_required method decorator on your class. Get rid of it, error will go away (and you shouldn't need to add a login_required decorator, the base class has one on the dispatch method already).

Comment: I tried that as well.  The problem is for sure `@classonlymethod`.  Will post an answer soon.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're so convinced it's the `@classonlymethod`. It doesn't at all prevent `as_view()` from being inherited, I've had many classes inherit from built-in views and `as_view()` always inherits and works just fine. If you add as_view() back in and remove the `@login_required` decorator, both the errors you're complaining about go away.